# Java Webservice- Amazon Cloud

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I've developed a web service in JAVA and now I need to deploy that service on Amazon cloud (EC2). What are the basic steps to follow in this regard? I'm really new to Amazon cloud lingo, some beginner-level links and/or examples would be highly appreciated

Comment: It might be confusing as there are many things to look at but there is no substitute to hard work when you want to get things done. start on Amazon site: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/   scroll down on the menu for the section "related resources" section and see "Documentation" --> http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ec2/. If you want to do things from your code, then also check Developer tools and Sample code libraries. They will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about Amazon Web Services is that there are so many different levels of services...  If you want a completely hands-off management experience, then [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk) might be a good starting point for you.  AWS Elastic Beanstalk gives you a managed container environment, available for several development environments.  All you have to do is drop your application in, and Elastic Beanstalk handles setting up load balancers, auto scaling rules, monitoring, alarms, etc.  Elastic Beanstalk is tailored towards web applications, but several web service frameworks, like Apache Axis, work directly through servlet containers like Tomcat, which make them a good fit for Elastic Beanstalk.

If you want to get your hands dirty with more of the details, then going directly to the services that Elastic Beanstalk orchestrates for you is your next option (ex: Amazon EC2, AutoScaling, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, etc.)

The [Getting Started section in the Amazon EC2 User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html) is a great place to start learning the basic EC2 concepts.  Following that guide should have you logged in to your own EC2 instance in just a few minutes!